# Get a file from URL and place it into Snowflake table

Tags: python-3.x, web, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a file that is sitting on the Web, get updated once every day. I need to put contents of this file into Snowflake table using Python script preferably. I am new to Snowflake and would really appreciate an advice on how to do it.

Comment: when you say "on the web" is it an API that you call?

Comment: I believe Mike is right, you need to explain better.  Is that API, ftp?

Comment: Here's an [example](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-use-Variable-Substitution-in-PUT-command-using-Snowflake-Python-connector) on how to use Python connector with PUT command, but in your case the file is not locally, it's somewhere `on the web` as you said.